# Pasar TODOS los Datos de un JTable a un ArrayList Multidimensional

Tags: java

me gustaría pasar los datos de un JTable a un ArrayList.
Mi idea era esta:

```
static List<ArrayList<String>> lista = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
String fila[];
for (int i = 0; i < tablaProductos.getRowCount(); i++) {
        fila = tablaProductos.rowAtPoint(i);
        lista.add(new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fila)));

    }      
}
```

Pero obviamente este código está mal porque rowAtPoint() requiere un Point y le estoy pasando un int.
¿Hay alguna forma de recorrer toda la tabla, y pasarle sus datos a un ArrayList multidimensional?